# Command to view logged on users in vsftpd?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I am using vsftpd installed on RHEL5.

I need to get the current logged on ftp users, so I issued `last|grep 'still'` but it didn't display the ftp users. What is the command to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `setproctitle_enable=YES` in `vsftpd.conf` and you can do a `ps aux` on host to see connected users.

Answer (score 0):

If your vsftpd is PAM-enabled, set `session_support` in `vsftpd.conf`.